# JdkSerializationRedisSerializer in Spring Boot does not change

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

My objects do not implement serialization and I do not want to rewrite for this. I tried to replace JdkSerializationRedisSerializer with Jackson2JsonRedisSerialize, I have tried many options but it doesn't change. What's the problem?

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory){
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    return redisTemplate;
  }
}
```

Error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [com.social.website.entity.user.User]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:33)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:94)
    ... 150 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [com.project.entity.User]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.Serializer.serializeToByteArray(Serializer.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:60)
    ... 152 more
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Same problem for me.

Comment: Are you trying to change it for use of @Cacheable or any other similar annotation or for use of RedisTemplate method calls?